# Using Control Adapter for User Controls in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, rendering

We can change the output rendering of an ASP.NET control with Control Adapters. Now I want to know that, is it possible to change a user control rendering by control adapters in ASP.NET?  By the way I have several user controls in my page and I don’t want to do same actions for them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can but you must define your controls childs as public in your User control

```
(Associate public on child controls in order to access from your adapter)

public class UserControlSample : userControl
{
  public TextBox TextBoxWrapper
  {
      get
      {
         return MyTextBox;
      }
      set
      {
         MyTextBox = value;
      }
  }
}


//Access from adapter
UserControlSample.TextBoxWrapper.Text  
UserControlSample.TextBoxWrapper.Id
.....
```

Comment: How can I access to child controls in adapter?